# Bringing a Git Repository and SVN Repo together

Tags: git, git-svn

I have to use a SVN Repo on my server. I checked the trunk once out and saved all changes to a local git repo, using branches etc.

What is the best way to get all the commits from my local git to the svn Server?
export it and import it in a git-svn clone?

what i have:
SVN Repo (rev: 1400)
GIT-SVN (rev: 1400)
local git (rev: 1700)

the branches in my git are simple, something like this:

> ```
> A---B-------------F---G
>                  /
>         C---D---E
> ```

Comment: i exported all commits with "git format-patch" for every branch and applied them to the "git svn" checkout with "git am" then i used dcommit, thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git svn dcommit` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You should have started with

```
git svn clone URL/project
```

And than you have a git repos where you can commit changes etc. If you think you're ready just do a

```
git svn dcommit
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you work must looks like (from the beginning)

```
mkdir {proj_name}
cd {proj_name}
git svn init -s https://example.com/svn/{proj_name}
git svn fetch
(many times)
   #make changes
   git commit
(many times)
git svn dcommit
```